# php hangs on Windows after code completion

Tags: php, windows, freeze

We're using PHP only as a script interpreter (no Apache/IIS).  We've encountered a situation where the PHP.exe process hangs after code completion.  I can confirm that the final line of code has executed (e.g., an echo to console of the return code) but the PHP.exe process remains.  Though the code does use exec() and passthru() at some points, logging confirms that control is passed back to the PHP process and it continues merrily along its way.

Using Process Hacker, I've found that there are always these three threads running:

- php.exe+0x2d78
- ntdll.dll!RtlSetLastWin32ErrorAndNtStatusFromNtStatus+0x59
- mswsock.dll+0x58ab

The address points are always the same in all cases.  All three threads report "State: Wait:UserRequest" and the php.exe and ntdll.dll threads have the same start time while the mswsock.dll starts a few seconds later.  Using Process Hacker's "Analyze" ability to see why they are hanging, it says that none of the threads appear to be waiting.

I find it odd that mswsock.dll is starting **after** the others -- no idea why that would be since the code has completed.  But it appears to me that php.exe is using the SetLastError() export to record the last error code but it isn't able to complete?

Any other ideas on what might be going on here?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of PHP do you use -- Thread Safe or Non Thread Safe and which version?

If the answer is "Thread Safe" and because you are using it in CLI mode only, I would recommend using Non Thread Safe build.

I do not know which code you are using there but it works fine here when using sockets (like, sending email via SMTP directly).

Comment: Using 5.3.2 VC6 x86 non-thread-safe build.  Good thought, though.  I continue to see, in every case, a thread for mswsock.dll which was started after the php.exe thread.  This morning, however, I found a system that had hung and was slightly different than the others.

Comment: If you can -- try upgrading to 5.3.6 VC9 (this may be problematic if you have custom extensions that were built with VC6 etc) as well as upgrade your extensions (if you cannot do it on the actual server then consider doing so on virtual copy). If there is a bug in PHP or bundled extension there is a good chance that it already has been fixed in recent builds.

Comment: Yes, I'd considered the upgrade but was was avoiding it for now.  This is on a lot of production systems and I wanted to better identify the issue.  In each instance, I continue to see a thread for mswsock.dll.  Since we are using the curl library I’m led to suspect there is something about curl’s communication that is not “letting go” and that this is what keeps the process hung.  Yet, though I kill the mswsock.dll thread, the php.exe thread still doesn’t go away – likely because it is still waiting on the mutext to clear.

Comment: The real challenge is that I cannot get this to happen.  It only happens randomly.  There are about 1000 systems running this and I see only one or two in a morning that hung.  Generally, never the same system, though I have two that have repeated multiple times.  So, if upgrade, I'll try one of them first.

Comment: You surely know the drill: _upgrade on test/dev server to test if your code is compatible first_. RE:curl -- we had a situation recently -- 2 servers running the same PHP version & extensions. After payment gateway updated their system (on their servers), one of our servers start throwing "Fatal Error" (or something like that) when communicating with payment gateway over HTTPS (simple POST request). Exactly the same code on both servers -- works fine on one and shows unrecoverable error on another. restarting did not helped. Upgraded PHP to a newer build and working fine since. Mystery...

Comment: I've continued to track this and believe I've found the issue.  In one location in the code, it was passing a null value for the timeout so I've corrected that and now watching to see if that was the cause.  I spoke with another engineer who said he'd encountered similar hangs when the timeout wasn't passed and then the connection was broken.  So, maybe...

Comment: Nope, didn't help.  Though I've been patching the systems where this has been occurring, I had one of those patched systems do it again this morning.  So, I'm back to square one.  Have to figure out what it is waiting on.  All of the threads (php.exe, mswsock.dll, ntdll.dll) are all at a state of Wait:UserRequest, always at the same address, and I need to figure out why.